# Unable to run Makefile targets in Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, make, windows-subsystem-for-linux, makefile

I feel I've tried everything but I feel I'm missing something really simple.. I'm trying to run a makefile from a project (which works fine on a Mac) on a Windows machine with WSL running but get a weird error.

I noticed the version of make in WSL is `0.8.1` which seemed old, so I've tried to upgrade to `3.81` with these steps:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-3.81.tar.gz
tarxvf make-3.81.tar.gz
cd make-3.81/
./configure
make
```

But, I get this output every time. I get the same output when I run a make command against the project as I do with the installation script.

```
davidn0rman@WSL-Ubuntu:/tmp/make-3.81$ make
make ℹ info Invoking all target
make ℹ info Invoking config.h target
make ℹ info Invoking stamp-h1 target
(node:13860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:13860) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13860) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not
handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
make ✖ ERR  not found: make-$(srcdir)/config.h.in

  $ make <target...> [options]

  Options:
    --help             Show this help output
    --version          Show package version
    --debug            Enable extended log output

  Targets:
    [targets in the Makefile list here]
```

If I try and `make -v` I get the following, but on the Mac I get the version and the copyright blurb.

```
davidn0rman@WSL-Ubuntu:/tmp$ make -v
make ✖ ERR  Missing Makefile / Bakefile
make ℹ info Run "make init" to generate a Makefile.
```

To say it's frustrating is putting it mildly, wondering if anyone has run across this before in WSL or Ubuntu? Node and npm are up to date.

Comment: *"version of make in WSL is 0.8.1"* that seems unlikely - it is 4.1 on mine. How did you determine this? Do you have multiple versions of `make` on your system? what is the output of `type -a make`?

Comment: When I ran `make -v` during the above process it gave `0.8.1`, although I now notice that was a folder with a Makefile present. Otherwise, I get the error at the end of my post.

Output of `type -a make` is:
`make is /usr/local/bin/make` and `make is /usr/bin/make`

Comment: I suspect that `/usr/local/bin/make` is [npm make](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make), and that's causing all your problems - you don't need to build `make`, you just need to make sure that your project finds `/usr/bin/make` first

Comment: You're right! `npm uninstall make -g` has fixed it. Thanks @steeldriver !

Answer (score 1):

As [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146289/unable-to-run-makefile-targets-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1#comment1903030_1146289) mentioned in this comment, I seemingly had npm make along side make itself.

- Run `type -a make`. Ideally you want `/usr/bin/make` to appear only, I also had `/usr/local/bin/make` which isn't needed.
- `npm uninstall make -g` to remove the latter instance of make.

This rectified the issue.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out a similar problem (just kept getting errors about make-info not being installed even though I'd installed it over and over) and this finally did it. I think at some point I installed make via npm for a project and since nvm's path is before the /usr/bin one, it's been taking precedence. Uninstalled the npm make and bam, everything's running smoothly. Can't upvote enough...